# How to fix: 'Error in unique >= 10 : comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types'

Tags: r

I want divide my data on train and test.

I calculated the percentile, and I want choose uniqe values for numeric variables

```
column <- c("NAME", "COUNTRY_CODE", "REGION_COUNTRY", "NACE_REV_2", 
            "CATEGORY_COMPANY", "TOTAL_ASSETS", "NET_CURRENT_ASSETS", 
            "FIXED_ASSETS", "NET_INCOME", "CAPITAL",  "WORKING_CAPITAL", 
            "LOANS", "CURRENT_RATIO", "ROA", "EBIT")

data <- PL_ALL[, column]

nums <- sapply(data, is.numeric) 

data.n <- data[, nums]

fact <- sapply(data, is.factor)

data.f <- data[, fact]

percentile <- apply(X=data.n, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x) 
  round(quantile(x, seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), na.rm=TRUE), 2))

#There is ok

numeric <- colnames(data.n[which(unique >= 10)])

num_as_fact <- colnames(data.n[which(unique < 10 & unique > 1)])
```

In line: 
`numeric<-colnames(data.n[which(unique>=10)])` 
I have a problem:

```
Error in unique >= 10 :comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

and similary in line:

`num_as_fact<-colnames(data.n[which(unique<10 & unique>1 )])` I have a problem:

```
Error in unique < 10 : comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

My data:

```
dput(head(baza.n,15))
    structure(list(TOTAL_ASSETS = c(8L, 11L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 32L), NET_CURRENT_ASSETS = c(-222L, 
-275L, -1281L, -353L, -97L, -48L, -16L, -8L, -70L, -642L, -375L, 
-236L, -50L, -476L, -1845L), FIXED_ASSETS = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 21L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), NET_INCOME = c(-1L, 
-1L, -2L, -1L, -9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -8L, -1L, -1L, 5L, -23L, 
-11L), CAPITAL = c(-210L, -274L, -1281L, 26L, 21L, -72L, -22L, 
-11L, 51L, 129L, -393L, 0L, 3L, -507L, 192L), WORKING_CAPITAL = c(-168L, 
-248L, -987L, -275L, -22L, -23L, -7L, -2L, -1L, -414L, -342L, 
-123L, -55L, -478L, -660L), LOANS = c(30L, 0L, 106L, 30L, 8L, 
25L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 89L, 1L, 83L, 5L, 0L, 671L), CURRENT_RATIO = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ROA = c(-13L, 
-9L, -14L, -3L, -56L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -37L, -5L, -4L, 16L, 
-79L, -31L), EBIT = c(-1L, -1L, 2L, -1L, -9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
-12L, -1L, -1L, -4L, -23L, -11L), WC.TA = c(-21, -22.55, -89.73, 
-18.33, -1.38, -1.35, -0.41, -0.11, -0.05, -18.82, -13.68, -4.39, 
-1.96, -16.48, -20.62), EBIT.TA = c(-0.12, -0.09, 0.18, -0.07, 
-0.56, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.55, -0.04, -0.04, -0.14, -0.79, -0.34)), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What's the `str` of data.n? It's unclear what `unique` is. unique expects an argument and it's unclear what the goal is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use the [appropriate formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/371738) in the future if you ask a question, this time we did it for you.

Comment: In data.n are only numeric variables. I want choose from data.n only those columns for which the number of unique values ​​is greater than or equal to 10 and next step for variables with more unique values ​​than 10, I want prepare a variable with categories

Comment: I would suggest replacing the output of `str` with the output of `dput(head(data.n,15))` in your question. Could you edit to do this replacement?

Comment: I replaced this in the question

Comment: You never defined `unique` so you seem to be using the buillt-in function `unique`, but if so, you are trying to use it without *applying* it to anything (which is sort of like trying to use it without using it). What is `unique >= 10` supposed to mean? Unique *what*? You are comparing an unevaluated function to a number.

Comment: When I used this code on other data, it works without a problem. On this data, when I want to see unique values `unique>=10` it's ok. But I want save column names of data.n, which unique values ​​meet this condition

Comment: @JohnColeman you're right. I lost line when I defined `unique`  I fixed it, and it works. Thank you